# preg_match_all : Assign same name to two subpatterns

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to use a regex to match two different subpatterns and give them the same name using the PCRE_INFO_JCHANGED modifier `(?J)`

The two subpatterns are very different from each other so I have to catch them using `|`

What I usually do is give the two patterns a different name and then choose the one I want using PHP, but I'd like to know if it possible without PHP

Example here : https://3v4l.org/GEMeT (*edited thanks to @JustOnUnderMillions*)

The 2nd `?P<number>` will always capture and replace the first `?P<number>`

**What I want :** Capture both patterns with one regex and store them both with the same key `number`

```
Desired output :

Pattern 1
string(1) "1"

Pattern 2
string(1) "2"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by offering a few sample inputs and their expected outputs?  As far as I can tell, `preg_match_all('/\d+/',$input,$out)` OR `preg_split('/[^\d]+/',$input,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` would do the job.  Let's keep your question moving toward a resolution so that future SO readers can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use preg_match_all here

```
$regex = '/(?J)I wanna match pattern (?P<number>1) which is very different from pattern 2|(?P<number>2), again nothing to do with pattern 1 here/';
```

Result with `preg_match`:

```
array(3) {
 [0]=>
 string(62) "I wanna match pattern 1 which is very different from pattern 2"
 ["number"]=>
 string(1) "1"
 [1]=>
 string(1) "1"
}
```

Full with fixed regex `'nothing similar' was not found in the orignal regex`:

```
$text1 = 'I wanna match pattern 1 which is very different from pattern 2';
$text2 = 'I wanna match pattern 2, again nothing similar with pattern 1 here';
$regex = '/(?J)(I wanna match pattern (?P<number>1) which is very different from pattern 2|I wanna match pattern (?P<number>2), again nothing similar with pattern 1 here)/';

echo "Pattern 1\n";
preg_match( $regex, $text1, $matches );
var_dump($matches);

echo "\n\nPattern 2\n";
preg_match( $regex, $text2, $matches );
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Does it mean it doesn't work at all with preg_match_all ? My real use case needs preg_match_all. Also thanks for the fix, I edited my question